# Rails - Is a date between two dates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm creating a system that needs to make sure planned "Trips" do not over lap. To do this I am trying to validate the start_date and end_date to make sure they are not within the start and end dates for another trip.

```
class TripdateValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator

  def validate_each(object, attribute, value)

      # Check value exists as end_date is optional
      if value != nil

          parsed_date = Date.parse(value)

          # is the start date within the range of anything in the db
         trips = Trip.where(['start_date >= ? AND end_date <= ? AND user_id = ?', parsed_date, parsed_date, object.user_id])

        # overlapping other trips, aghhh
        object.errors[attribute] << 'oh crap' if trips
      end
  end
end
```

The date is coming from a type="date" field which is powered by jQuery UI Datepicker and contains the format 2011-01-01. This gets to rails as 2011-01-30 00:00:00 UTC which I don't fully understand.

If I try to use Date.parse() on this value it gives the error:

> TypeError in TripsController#create
>
> $_ value need to be String (nil given)
>
> Rails.root:
>   /Users/phil/Sites/travlrapp.com
>   Application Trace | Framework Trace |
>   Full Trace
>
> app/models/trip.rb:29:in
>   `validate_each'
>
>   app/controllers/trips_controller.rb:75:in`
>   create'
>   app/controllers/trips_controller.rb:74:in
>   `create'

Whenever I run the query, nothing is returned. Could this be a date format issue, is my logic broken or am I doing something really stupid? Been stuck on this a while and google is no help.

**Edit** People are focusing on the Date.parse error but that is not the main problem. Where im stuck is that I don't understand how to do date comparisons when everything is in totally different formats.

I have swapped Date.parse() for Chronic.parse() and now I am getting the following SQL queries generated:

```
 SELECT "trips".* FROM "trips" WHERE (start_date >= '2011-01-26 00:00:00.000000' AND end_date <= '2011-01-26 00:00:00.000000' AND user_id = 19)
```

This returns nothing. The dates I am testing against are:

start: 2011-02-17 00:00:00.000000
end: 2011-02-21 00:00:00.000000

Seeing as I think dates are being formatted properly now it seems more like a logic problem. How the heck can I validate overlapping dates >.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Squeel power FTW!!! I'm sure you will love it

$ gem install squeel

model.rb

```
Model.where{date_colum > 10.years.ago & date_column < DateTime.now}
```

Comment: This is a great solution, except the above would probably have to be: ```Model.where{(date_colum > 10.years.ago) & (date_column < DateTime.now)}```

Answer (score 4):

For those that land here, check the [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) on Range conditions:

```
Client.where(created_at: (Time.now.midnight - 1.day)..Time.now.midnight)
```

That will produce the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM clients WHERE (clients.created_at BETWEEN '2008-12-21 00:00:00' AND '2008-12-22 00:00:00')
```

So you can search for fields between two dates using a range.

Comment: This works great and it's part of Rails.  I was even able to use strings: `where(created_at:'2016-05-12 09:00'..'2016-05-12 10:00')`

Answer (score 3):

I'm responding to your edit, mostly, and I think you're not getting any results for two reasons:

First:  I suspect your parser is giving you DateTime objects, while you really just want plain Date objects.  Pass a DateTime into Rails's SQL query generator, and it gives you a `'YYYY-MM-DD hh.mm.ss.uuu...'` string, while the database expects just a plain `'YYYY-MM-DD'` string for date column comparison; the DB date parser fails, gives back NULL, all comparisons with NULL fail, etc., and you get back an empty result set.

Change `parsed_date` to `parsed_date.to_date` and you should be okay on that front.

Second:  Take a look at your SQL, this chunk in particular `start_date >= ? AND end_date <= ?`.  It looks to me like it'll only detect a collision if the trip you're checking against has a start date that's later than its end date.

So try `start_date <= ? AND end_date >= ?` or `? BETWEEN start_date AND end_date`, which I personally prefer, as it's a bit more readable.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

For overlap validation you can try one of these gems https://github.com/chrisb87/range_validator or https://github.com/robinbortlik/validates_overlap

Answer (score 2):

I prefer:

```
Model.where{date_colum >> (10.years.ago..Datetime.now)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with the `TimeZone` class:

```
parsed_date = Time.zone.parse(value)
```

Here's the docs:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html#method-i-parse

Comment: I'm using Chronic::parser() now but I still have the problem of comparing the dates in the query. I assumed if I passed ActiveRecord the DateTime object it would be able to convert it. Does it or not? Either way my results are all empty when they should have data.

Comment: One strange thing is that the error message says that there's a nil value instead of a string. That doesn't look possible from the code you've given if that error is raised by the parse call. Maybe giving us the full stack trace would help.

Comment: Strange, the stacktrace clearly says that nil is being sent as the first argument to Data.parse. I'd say the error doesn't originate from the validator code you posted. Is there anything else at line 29 (or 30 with the latest stacktrace) of app/models/trip.rb?

Comment: There is nothing affecting the value. If I add a puts value right before the Date.parse() I get "2011-01-26 00:00:00 UTC", which weirdly is not the value in POST as I only send 2011-01-26. http://d.pr/lWPU

Comment: Really weird! What is the value class?

Answer (score 0):

I would log the "value" and see if it's remotely close to something that Date.parse() can handle.  If it looks parsable see if  Date.parse works on it in irb and if so check it in console env (./script/console or rails c)  for your app.  That should track down the problem.

Comment: This is not the main problem here. I need to parse the date somehow, and make something that rails can use to compare my date to the dates in the database. As I said the string is 2011-01-30 00:00:00 UTC which date.parse SHOULD be fine with. Once that is parsed, how the heck can I get it into a format that both my local SQLite will be happy with, as well as Postgres on Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
overlaps = Trip.where(
    "(DATEDIFF(start_date, ?) * DATEDIFF(?, end_date)) >= 0",
    self.end_date,
    self.start_date
)
```

It basically says this:

> If each start date looks toward the other's end date, are they looking
>   in the same direction? Then they overlap.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cover method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F)

it's returns true if data between selected range otherwise false